# How to Capture previous row value and perform subtraction

Tags: sas

How to Capture previous row value and perform subtraction

[image]

Refer Table 1 as main data, Table 2 as desired output, Let me explain you in detail, Closing_Bal is derived from (Opening_bal - EMI) for eg if (20 - 2) = 18, as value 18 i want in 2nd row under opening_bal column then ( opening_bal - EMI) and so till new LAN , If New LAN available then start the loop again ,

i have created lag function butnot able to run loop

Comment: Where does the EMI = 3 value come from in obs = 2?

Comment: Good catch Peter , EMI column in second table is left joined from other table

Comment: Please include that in your question. Makes it much easier to provide code for you.

Comment: Sure Peter will include it

Comment: Thank you. Otherwise, nobody are able to provide you an accurate answer.

Comment: Agreed .. I revised the question Peter please check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
data A;
input Month $ LAN Opening_Bal EMI Closing_Bal;
infile datalines dlm = '|' dsd;
datalines;
1_Nov|1|20|2|18 
2_Dec|1|  |3|   
3_Jan|1|  |5|   
4_Feb|1|  |3|   
1_Nov|2|30|4|26 
2_Dec|2|  |3|   
3_Jan|2|  |2|   
4_Feb|2|  |5|   
5_Mar|2|  |6|   
;

data B(drop = c);
   set A;
   by LAN;

   if first.LAN then c = Closing_Bal;

   if Opening_Bal = . then do;
      Opening_Bal = c;
      Closing_Bal = Opening_Bal - EMI;
      c = Closing_Bal;
   end;

   retain c;
run;
```

**Result:**

```
Month  LAN  Opening_Bal  EMI  Closing_Bal
1_Nov  1    20           2    18
2_Dec  1    18           3    15
3_Jan  1    15           5    10
4_Feb  1    10           3    7
1_Nov  2    30           4    26
2_Dec  2    26           3    23
3_Jan  2    23           2    21
4_Feb  2    21           5    16
5_Mar  2    16           6    10
```

Comment: Peter you are great it’s working fine .. thanks a lot from my side .. all the best

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you already have CLOSING_BAL on the input dataset, so when the SET statement reads a new observation it will overwrite the value calculated on the previous observation.  Either drop or rename the variable in the source dataset.

Example:

```
data have;
  input Month $ LAN Opening_Bal EMI Closing_Bal;
datalines;
1_Nov 1 20  2 18 
2_Dec 1  .  3  .   
3_Jan 1  .  5  .  
4_Feb 1  .  3  .  
1_Nov 2 30  4 26 
2_Dec 2  .  3  .  
3_Jan 2  .  2  .  
4_Feb 2  .  5  .  
5_Mar 2  .  6  .  
;

data want;
  set have (drop=closing_bal);
  retain Closing_Bal;
  Opening_Bal=coalesce(Opening_Bal,Closing_Bal);
  Closing_bal=Opening_bal - EMI ;
run;
```

Results:

```
                       Opening_           Closing_
Obs    Month    LAN       Bal      EMI       Bal

 1     1_Nov     1        20        2        18
 2     2_Dec     1        18        3        15
 3     3_Jan     1        15        5        10
 4     4_Feb     1        10        3         7
 5     1_Nov     2        30        4        26
 6     2_Dec     2        26        3        23
 7     3_Jan     2        23        2        21
 8     4_Feb     2        21        5        16
 9     5_Mar     2        16        6        10
```

Comment: Tom you are too great , it’s working fine .. you both guys are the best .. all the best

Comment: Tom, How coalesce works in this ?

Comment: Look up how coallesce() works. In this case it is there to capture the non-missing values from the input file.  When the beginning variable is missing in the input file then the missing value is replaced with retained value of the ending value.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this works

```
data B;
   set A;
   by lan;
   if not first.lan then do;
      opening_bal = lag(closing_bal);
      closing_bal = opening_bal - EMI;
   end;
run;
```

because you don't execute `lag` for each observation.

Comment: Not working mate